# Previous value in the same column Power Bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

If it possible to somehow refer to the previous value in the same column? I know there is option to use it in next column.[image]
But it not really fit for me because I need some logic like this. If (calculation value>check value; yes value; previous value). I got error " A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation " When I am trying refer back.

Comment: Add a new column in the underlying query using `tablename[column_name]{[Index]-1}` syntax

Comment: Add a new column offset by 1 from the original column.  Or do an internet search for `power query previous row`.  Plenty of tutorials and examples there.

Comment: I tried this way "tablename[column_name]{[Index]-1}" But I cannot refer back because I got this error. I do not want to take previous value from other column I need previous calculated field. For example ( in brackets there we will be values) if ( column1(5)+column2(3)>10; column1(5)+column2(3); previous value). So I can do for example column1 and column2 previous values in new columns but it will not work if I need to get value earlier then 1 row back. Because it will work for one value back. But if I need 2 or more it will not. That's why I need to refer to previous value in the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** I understand what you want to do correctly, you can accomplish that with the `List.Generate` function.  You generate a list according to your rules; then combine it with the original table.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTJVitWJBpI6SsZgljmQZQJmGQFZlmCWMZBlBGaZAVlmSrGxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),

//create conditional adding column 
   c1 = #"Changed Type"[Column1],
   c2 = #"Changed Type"[Column2],
    conditionalAdd = List.Generate(
            ()=>[res= if c1{0} + c2{0} > 10 then c1{0}+c2{0} else 0, idx=0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(c1),
            each [res=if c1{[idx]+1} + c2{[idx]+1} > 10 then c1{[idx]+1} + c2{[idx]+1} else [res],idx=[idx]+1],
            each [res]),

    //combine with original table
    newTable = 
        Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & {conditionalAdd},
            Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type") & {"Conditional Add"}
        )
in
   newTable
```

**Source**
[image]

**newTable**
[image]